# SQL Database Structure. Normalisation?

Tags: sql, database, schema

If I have four tables, each with four columns, which use the primary key from 'users', which is 'id' and is of type int, and the relationship between the tables are only ever one to one, is it still appropriate to have the tables separate with 'id' as the only foreign key, instead of one table with 16 columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd ask what the JOIN is buying you in that case.  Either one table is all you need or the statement that it'll always be a one-to-one relationship could change.  If it's the former, I'd denormalize.  If it's the latter, I'd keep the multiple table design.

Comment: OK that makes good sense. I think I'll stick to some form of normalisation, in case of any future changes. Thanks Duffymo.

Comment: Can you please state which normal form each proposed design is in? The reason I ask is that I don't think this has anything to do with normalization but I'm prepared to be corrected ;)

Comment: ...I can only think you've confused the [principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design) (POOD) with the [principle of full normalization](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/3010532.htm) (POFN).

Answer (score 0):

There are often reasons for using a de-normalised database schema such as performance or better conceptualisation. However given the information you've provided it sounds like you would be better off with a single table. Having 3 tables with 1-to-1 associations and only 4 columns each seems a bit strange.

Comment: I see. Well, this database is for a small online game I'm developing. Each table represents related groups of entities within the game.